# How to inject JavaScript to WebView whenever required?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, android-webview

This [link](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/) shows how to inject JavaScript code to `WebView` object in Android. However it's available only once, via `onPageFinished(webView,url)`, when the page is finished loading.

Is there a way (how ?) to keep that "injection" ability "forever", whenever necessary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use :

```
  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello')");
```